# How can content be pulled from Wordpress?

Tags: ios, wordpress

Is it possible to do some API call and pull Wordpress content? Or is that not a possibility?

I am trying to get my blog's content and display it in a mobile (iPhone) app. Would anyone know how to best accomplish that?

Thank you!

Comment: Maybe [Jetpack](http://wordpress.org/plugins/jetpack/)'s JSON API module.

Comment: @brasofilo Interesting. I thought there was maybe some JSON call I could make?

Answer (score 2):

You need to install [this](http://wordpress.org/plugins/json-api/) plugin. It provides a lot of APIs which you can call including:-

- get_recent_posts
- get_posts
- get_post
- get_page

example usage:-

```
http://your-site-name.com/api/get_post?id=1
```

will return post (in JSON) with id 1

You can also create post, update post and delete post using some APIs provided by this plugin.